# How to give same button size for all screen size in android?

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android and I am designing a screen with two buttons(cancel & Next )in android and the button size should be same.It is normally working 3 inches screen in portrait but when i rotate the mobile to Landscape the size is not same as in portrait.I have used android:weight also and i did not find any changes .could some one help me out of this...thanks in advance.

Comment: Set button size using `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` with `dp` units.

Comment: how to design the button in android?

Comment: Please follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) guide

Answer (score 0):

try to set width and height with dp unit but keep it in your mind your button may larger than screen size when run on small screen device.